# How to call multiple widgets in dart files on another dart file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-dependencies

I created some dart files from AdobeXD (**applebutton.dart**, **background.dart**, **googlebutton.dart**). However, I don't know how to call these files from the **main.dart** file.

[image]

I can copy and paste part of these AbodeXD generated files into the main.dart file, but I believe there must be a way to call these files without making main.dart bigger.

[image]
*Inside class MyApp> Widget> body> children, I pasted the Container from background.dart, but I want to call the Widget instead of copying it.*

(I am new in flutter so thanks for your answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These all pages have main function. It's not understandable for Dart. Dart files search main function to start, this is why you must use just one main function into your main.dart file.

To use your other screens in the main.dart file, use import keyword on the top of your main.dart files and write the page's path.

The screens must extends with StatelessWidget or StatefulWidget. You're not compile your entire application when you want to show another page, so you dont need to use main() function in each page.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution will be creating another widget just for export and importing just one file.

In this image, I just need to import `widgets.dart`. The rest of the file will be imported there.

**widgets.dart**

```dart
export 'widget.circleNeonBorder.dart';
export 'widget.rectNeonBorder.dart';
export 'widget.desktopWrapper.dart';
export 'widget.tabletWrapper.dart';
export 'widget.mobileWrapper.dart';
```

There is `Dart Barrel File Generator` extension for Vs-code user. You may also find for android-studio.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using items from a different file, you must first import them using the `import` keyword, like so:

`import 'Widgets/my_widget.dart'`;

another way to import is by calling the full path of the widget:

`import 'package:my_project/widgets/my_widget.dart'`;

most IDEs will give you an option to auto import whatever files you use

[image]

Comment: And once it is imported, how do I use it (e.g., the class and widget in the first image I posted), sorry? Thank you.

Comment: so you've gotta do some things to the files before you can use them (also my guess is that there is a way to ask adobeXD to do this automatically, but I don't know how) first remove these lines: `void main() {...}` then rename the widget to whatever you want, where it says `class MyApp` finally  your widget is surrounded by a MaterialApp and a Scaffold, MaterialApp means the widget is an app, so if it's a button you should remove it, and Scaffold means that the widget is a page in the app, so if you made a whole page you shouldn't remove it, but if it is, for example, a button, also remove it.

Comment: As I said, there's probably a way for adobeXD to do this automatically, however I don't use it, so I wouldn't know.

Comment: Thank you!! I 1) removed the main part on each file, 2) change the name for each class, 3) use runApp in the main.dart file to call each class. It worked! Thanks!!